# Check value existing in a array of object using a list of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash

I've scratching my head solving this. I even tried lodash but no luck. The challenge is to check a list of username with a list of username.

A username is made up of first and last name with dynamic variable in the middle so

```
const suggestion_username = [
    fname + "&" + lname,
    fname + "+" + lname,
    fname + "." + lname,
    fname + lname
]
```

I want to map it with existed name so in db I have

```
const existed_name = [
{username:'something'},
{username:'john.james'},
{username:'johnjames'}
]
```

so if the result I want would be

```
[
        {username:fname + "&" + lname,taken:0},
        {username:fname + "+" + lname,taken:0},
        {username:fname + "." + lname,taken:1}, //taken
        {username:fname + lname,taken:1}, //taken
    ]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: tried _.map and _.each. You wouldn't want my see my messup solution that doesn't work, it will confused u more here.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
const fname = 'John';
const lname = 'James';

const suggestions = [
    "&", "+", ".", ""
];

const available_usernames = suggestions.map((sep) => {
    const genUsername = {username: `${fname}${sep}${lname}`};
    if (existed_username.find(username => username === genUsername.username)) {
        return Object.assign(genUsername, {taken: 1});
    } 
    return Object.assign(genUsername, {taken: 0});
});
```

If the suggestions array is rewritten as separators only, the map method can be used to turn it into a new array by replacing each suggestion separator with an object with the suggested username and whether it's taken or not.

The find method returns the first element of the array that satisfies the condition (i.e. the suggested username matches an existing username) or undefined. We can use this to populate the taken field in each object of our new array.

The output should be:

```
[
    {username: 'John&James', taken: 0},
    {username: 'John+James', taken: 0},
    {username: 'John.James', taken: 1},
    {username: 'JohnJames', taken: 1},
]
```

See working pen here: http://codepen.io/Smmaca/pen/gwNRKK?editors=0011

Comment: nice but what is find method, is that es6?

Comment: No it's just another Array.prototype method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). I suggest you look at all Array.prototype methods so you know what tools you have to work with when solving problems such as this :)